# Spring Batch - process repeated when skippable exception occurs

Tags: spring-batch

My CSV file has following data:

```
1.a   <- skippable exception occurs
2.b   <- skippable exception occurs
3.1   <- process OK data
4.c   <- skippable exception occurs
5.d   <- skippable exception occurs
```

When processing normal(no exception occurs) data, 
ItemProcess repeats this process.

For example, in upper situation's process is like this:

```
1.a 
2.b
3.1
4.c
3.1  <- This is my problem. Why does process repeat this data again?
```

I has set skip-limit and commit-interval, but problem remains.

Is there any other setting in my spring batch configuration?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get the issue. Are you saying if the same data in another line of CSV, reader should NOT return that line to processor?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021966/springbatch-does-rollback-though-no-rollback-exception-classes-are-defined/22022583#22022583 for a possible answer

Comment: @NghiaDo Sorry, I edited my question, second 1 is a repeated process, not same data in another line.

Comment: Are y expecting the last line 3,1 not be processed?

Comment: @Nghia Do Yes, but I found the reason. I was returning a new object when no-exception data processed in process(). I changed to return null, and repeating problem has gone. But when I do this, write() in Writer has empty parameter. This is my new problem..